# iTextSharp and Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, itext

I'm trying to use  iTextSharp dll in an Xamarin App, but I´m not able to compile because I´ve received this error:

```
Error       Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'System.Drawing.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver)   App2.Android    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets   1399    2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Xamarin Port.

> Xam.iTextSharpLGPL ( Install-Package Xam.iTextSharpLGPL)

You can download package from NuGet
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.iTextSharpLGPL/

Comment: Thanks! Now is ok!

Comment: @PieroZito Did you find alternative of `Xam.iTextSharpLGPL`?

Comment: That is based on an ancient version of iText (released on Jul 7 2009) that will never get updates or bugfixes.
iText Software is currently researching a Xamarin port of iText 7, which *will* continue to get updates. Contact iText Software's to add your weight to this feature request.

Comment: @PieroZito I use `Xam.iTextSharpLGPL` (updated in 2015), can you provide link if you know any other option. Your above comments says `researching` which is not surprising as Xamarin is still evolving

Comment: @GauravKP, I'm using that old version based on iTextSharp v.4.1.6. This version should be the last LGPL version than they have changed the license.

Another option can be PdfBOX but I've received errors about some duplicate resources, I've found that the problem is caused by IKVM.

Comment: @GauravKP Can I use this for Xamarin.iOS? Thanks!