# Xamarian Crossplatform

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am new in Xamarian cross platform.I am unable to install any package in my project.
I need ITextSharp package to install in my project.
Any suggestion about my project.
or is there any installation error my visual studio 2017 V15.6.6

Here you find my project backup.
 https://transfer.pcloud.com/download.html?code=5Z1KYY7Z1tqniyz5QUVZDoDVZswIUny3aQ8BrUrsQ9o7s1z6iCPtk

Please give me suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iTextSharp and Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391075/itextsharp-and-xamarin)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you. Duplicate means?

Comment: I have shared my back up.Could please look and tell me the issuie

Comment: Actually I can't installed any packages

Comment: "I can't install" is meaningless.  What errors or exceptions to do you get?  What IDE/platform are you using?  What have you tried to do to fix the problem?  You should NOT just post your project code and expect us to download it and debug it for you.  SO is not here to do your job for you.

Comment: I have tried....but i can't install the package ....I don't  know the reason ....even update is not possible for packages.

Comment: Anyway thank you for your support...

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the following document:

1. [iTextSharp: Any support for dotnet core (netstandard1.6)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40236194/itextsharp-any-support-for-dotnet-core-netstandard1-6)
2. [iTextSharp with a Windows 10 Universal App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40236194/itextsharp-any-support-for-dotnet-core-netstandard1-6)

**As you could find in the document, the problem that `.NET Standard` is not supported by `iTextSharp`.**

**`iText` Software has published a Xamarin port of `iText 7`**, which will continue to get updates. I think you could use `itext7` instead, I have tested it on my side, I could install the [itext7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV9nj.jpg) without any problem.