# Xamarian Crossplatform Itextsharp

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am new in Xamarian cross platform.I am unable to install any package in my project.
I need ITextSharp package to install in my project.

I try to install but I got some error:-

> Install-Package : NU1202: Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle 4.1.6 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0). Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle 
>   4.1.6 supports:
>     - net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
>     - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0)
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>
> Install-Package : NU1202: Package iTextSharp 5.5.13 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0). Package iTextSharp 5.5.13 supports: net 
>   (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>
> Install-Package : NU1202: Package BouncyCastle 1.7.0 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0). Package BouncyCastle 1.7.0 supports:
>     - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0)
>     - net40-client (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client)
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>
> Install-Package : NU1202: Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle 4.1.6 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win. Package 
>   iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle 4.1.6 supports:
>     - net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
>     - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0)
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>
> Install-Package : NU1202: Package BouncyCastle 1.7.0 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win. Package BouncyCastle 1.7.0 supports:
>     - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0)
>     - net40-client (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client)
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>
> Install-Package : NU1202: Package iTextSharp 5.5.13 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win. Package iTextSharp 5.5.13 supports: net 
>   (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>
> Install-Package : NU1202: Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle 4.1.6 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x64. Package 
>   iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle 4.1.6 supports:
>     - net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
>     - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0)
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>
> Install-Package : NU1202: Package BouncyCastle 1.7.0 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x64. Package BouncyCastle 1.7.0 supports:
>     - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0)
>     - net40-client (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client)
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>
> Install-Package : NU1202: Package iTextSharp 5.5.13 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x64. Package iTextSharp 5.5.13 supports: net 
>   (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>
> Install-Package : NU1202: Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle 4.1.6 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x86. Package 
>   iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle 4.1.6 supports:
>     - net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
>     - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0)
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>
> Install-Package : NU1202: Package BouncyCastle 1.7.0 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x86. Package BouncyCastle 1.7.0 supports:
>     - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0)
>     - net40-client (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client)
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>
> Install-Package : NU1202: Package iTextSharp 5.5.13 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x86. Package iTextSharp 5.5.13 supports: net 
>   (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>
> Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'HomeApplication_V4.iOS'.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle -Version 4.1.6
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>   Any suggestion about my project.

Please give me suggestion.
what I need to do about  xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win.
I have tried with Itextsharp V4.17 also but error remain same.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error NU1202 Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle 4.1.7 is not compatible with monoandroid71 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1). Package iTextSharp-LGPL-BouncyCastle 4.1.7 supports:
  - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0)
  - net40-client (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client)    
Error NU1202 Package iTextSharp 5.5.13 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0). Package iTextSharp 5.5.13 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)

Comment: Please don't add further details as comments, but rather **Edit** your question.

Answer (score 0):

The version you tried to install is not compatible with Xamarin. You'll have to install the Xamarin port of the library. It is based on the version 4.1.6 and hence LGPL licensed, which is way more permissive than the Affero GPL the more current versions of iTextSharp are licensed under. Anyway, it's not maintained. On NuGet there is exactly one version (0.1.0) which has been uploaded about three years ago. If it suffices, fine, but I'd test thoroughly (at least the features you need).

It is available from Nuget (see [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.iTextSharpLGPL/)) or Bitbucket ([here](https://bitbucket.org/smarongiu/xam.itextsharplgpl)).

FWIW, there is a port of PdfSharp for Xamarin, too (see [here](https://github.com/roceh/PdfSharp.Xamarin)), but it does not seem as if it's maintained, too.

Comment: I try to install LGPL V0.1.0-
+ Install-Package Xam.iTextSharpLGPL -Version 0.1.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
 
Install-Package : NU1202: Package BouncyCastle 1.7.0 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0). Package BouncyCastle 1.7.0 supports:
  - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0)
  - net40-client (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client)

Comment: So, what you suggest in this regards.Actually I need that package to create some report in pdf format in my mobile application.

Comment: Actually I don't know. I installed Xam.iTextSharpLGPL successfully in an iOS project. There are no dependencies towards BouncyCastle for me.

Comment: Thank you sir for your valuable time....I don't know this package will serve my purpose or not  but I should try......

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to my answer: [Install itext7 in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49968987/xamarian-crossplatform/50038392#50038392)

`iText Software` has published a Xamarin port of `iText 7`, which will supported `.NET Standard 1.6` and above.

In your Xamarin Forms project, you could install the `itext7` nuget package instead.