# Generate PDF Xamarin.Forms NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, itext, itext7

I am trying to generate a PDF from a Xamarin.Forms application.

In the IOS simulator, I get System.NotImplementedException on document.Add function

Code:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(filenamepdf));
Document document = new Document(pdf);
String line = "Hello! Welcome to iTextPdf";
document.Add(new Paragraph(line));
document.Close();
```

How should IText be used on Xamarin?

IText version: 7.1.13

Comment: You could check the link below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44391318/11850033

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to open the doc

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(filenamepdf));
Document document = new Document(pdf);
document.Open();
......
document.Close();
```